# "Squeezing" GameObject between two other GameObjects?

Tags: c#, collision-detection, unity-game-engine

I am trying to "squeeze" a GameObject, when Squeezer1 and Squeezer2 *both* have collided with it and continue to move towards each other. I wish to reduce width (x scale) so that total area of GameObject is maintained **while still being between the two Squeezers**. Because I'm not an advanced programmer, could someone provide me with a ready-to-deploy script?[image]

This question is strongly related to this one: [Question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/110322/squeezing-a-game-object-based-on-distance-to-another-game-object)

Comment: Dude you need to provide more details like - do the Squeezer objects have rigidbodies and colliders? are they moved by script or by physics? can they move all the way and touch one another? You can not have a ready-to-deploy script if don't provide any details about the environment you need your script to work in. please don't take me rude, best of luck!

Comment: The Squeezer objects are moved by script, have rigibodies and colliders, and can move all the way. Can you write an answer, please? @NikaKasradze

Comment: this is an old problem .. here's the FULL SOLUTION  http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/432033/view.html

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to build an object hierarchy
2. Your root object has nothing but a transform(kupMaster)
3. There are 3 different gameObjects under root object
4. First one has all the properties of cube except colliders which is called
   cubeProps.
5. Second one has a transform and a box collider and this collider just
       a regular one which stretches whole cube.This object has a script also and we will handle squeze things with this script.
6. Third one has a trasnform and a box collider as well. When cube is squezed cube will have it's scale so you need to define it's scale what shahe you want your cube have when it is squezed.

This is the Design
[image]

How does script work?

- it has box, squezedbox, defaultScale , speed and counter.
- **squezed box -->** squzedBox object which is signed with blue-gray color on design.
- **box-->**  cubeProps object which is signed with green color on design.
- **defaultScale-->** will be your default scale. You can assign it in Start() Method. It will have box's scale.
- **speed-->** it is the value make your cube squezing or releasing look like a spring.

**it is important that we are going to change scale of box's object(cubeProps) because it has mesh renderer component.**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class normalBoxScript : MonoBehaviour {

    private int counter;
    public GameObject box;
    public GameObject squezeBox;
    private Vector3 defaultScale;
    public float speed;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        defaultScale = box.transform.localScale;
    }
    void Update () {
        Debug.Log(counter);
         updateScale();
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
       if (col.tag == "Player")
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.tag == "Player")
        {
            counter--;
        }
    }

    void updateScale()
    {
        if (counter == 2)
        {
           box.transform.localScale = Vector3.MoveTowards(box.transform.localScale, squezeBox.transform.localScale, speed); 
        }
        else 
        {
            box.transform.localScale = Vector3.MoveTowards(box.transform.localScale, defaultScale, speed); 
        }
  }
 }
```

And The result
[image]

Comment: Because I'm not an advanced programmer, I need a ready-to-deploy script like mentioned in the question.

Comment: Open bounty worth +200 reputation started for a ready-to-deploy script!

Comment: Thank you for the edit, but in order to receive +200 reputation, you have to provide a ready-to-deploy ***script***.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that. Can you convert it to text so we can be able to just copy & paste it?

Comment: @Dimitri how can i share text here? You only need to write a  script looking this one.

Comment: Just edit your answer and convert [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qCUVX.png) to an actual script that we can copy & paste. Keep the image though, just add the text script.

Comment: Can you upload the Unity project of this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AYcrV.png) so we can better understand what you demonstrated, and try it for ourselves?

Comment: you want to see a gif?

Comment: No, I want the Unity project file of this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AYcrV.png). You can upload it anywhere (Dropbox, Google Drive etc.)

Comment: @Dimitri I think this is not appropriate in SO.

Comment: I think you didn't understand me. Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33957533/5622430) for example. It has received +100 reputation and the user has **uploaded an example project to Dropbox with a link.**

Comment: What you have uploaded does not open. I think you have to upload the **entire** Unity project folder (with `Assets`, `Library` etc.)

Comment: Your link is broken and I get `error 404`. The page says: _"The file you’re looking for has been moved or deleted."_ Upload a new one.

Comment: Your project has now been successfully uploaded. But, I would like you to avoid [this effect](http://s1.postimg.org/vkxec0dwf/image.png) and completely remove the `speed` factor and replace it with the proximity of the two spheres. And depending on the proximity, you adjust the scale of the Box. Because `speed` does not suit all conditions.

Comment: @Dimitri you want it to increase and decrease immediately and become the box smaller depends on the distance two boxes?

Comment: Yes. Isn't that more realistic?

Comment: decrease or increase depending on the distance looks realistic if you want detail but increasing or decreasing size immediately seems unrealistic

Comment: Just remove [this effect](http://s1.postimg.org/vkxec0dwf/image.png) and we'll continue this discussion once the effect is fixed.

Comment: In [this effect](http://s1.postimg.org/vkxec0dwf/image.png), the two Spheres are not touching the Box.

Comment: @BurakKarasoy Did you figure it out?

Comment: @BurakKarasoy I am also interested in a response because I need to accept your answer.

Comment: @JamieWright Ok, i have a work to finish. I will take a look at it so soons as it is done

Comment: @JamieWright I made a little change. From now on it is up to you. https://www.dropbox.com/s/fosd204gkav8r6u/exampleProject.rar?dl=0 I am done with this question GL

Comment: @BurakKarasoy Are you sure? I might put this question up for bounty in the future. Your project is not working as I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only working with cubes that have three components (lengthX, lengthY, lengthZ), and the squeeze is always perpendicular to the surface (meaning angles wont change), you can basicaly reduce the problems into finding two components when one is fixated. In your exemple, width is set to the distance between the faces of the two squeezing cubes and as you need to conserve area, you can deduce height.

```
Area = Width * Height
Height = Area / NewWidth
Width = NewWidth
```

In three dimensions you can assume the two components you want to deduce are equal...

As I'm writing this I think you could simulate this correctly by using springs. Each edges of your square/cube is a spring connecting the corners. Roughness of the spring is to be defined and the l0 should be the length you are considering.

A little reminder of spring equation :

```
Let F be the force exerced by a spring
l0 the length of the spring at rest
l the current length of the spring
k a constant that tweak the force (equivalent to the roughness of the spring)

F = k * (l - l0)
```

The spring alone will not conserve the area if the squashing is perpendicular to the surface. In this case you'll need to update *l0* of the unsquashed dimension.

Comment: Replace `l` with `y` and `l0` with `ou` :)

Comment: Because I'm not an advanced programmer, I need a ready-to-deploy script like mentioned in the question.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not meant to just have someone else write all the code for you. The idea is that you use this advice and write the code yourself.

Comment: Open bounty worth +200 reputation started for a ready-to-deploy script!